# How to convert multiple JSON files from different folders into a csv file

Tags: r, json, csv

I have several folders with a specific name that contain several JSON files. What I want is to put the JSON files for **each** folder together and convert each set of JSON files into a csv file with the name of the folder. Then I would like to put these csv files in specific a path of my computer. From the json file, I only want the **'data'** data (below an example of the structure of my json file).

For example, in the path '/in_my_path' I have 3 folders with the names 'name1', 'name2' and 'name3' respectively. Each folder contains several JSON files. I would like to create  3 csv files with the names "name1", "name2" and "name3".

What I tried so far:

```
  json_list<-list.files(path ="path of all the folders ", full.names =TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
  name_list <-list.dirs(path ="path of all the folders ", full.names=FALSE, recursive= FALSE)


 for(name in name_list){
 json_toBe_combined <-c()
 for(json in json_list){
 if(grepl(name, json)){
 json_toBe_combined <- c(json_toBe_combined, json)
  
   } else {
     next
          }

  name <- paste("table", name, sep = "_")
  result <- assign(name,lapply(json_toBe_combined, fromJSON))
    }
      }


   if(length(result) > 0) {
    L <- list()
     for (i in 1:length(result)) {    
       L[[i]] <- result[[i]][["data"]]
          name2 <- paste("Dataframe", trend, sep = "_")
           result2 <- assign(name2, Reduce(full_join, L))
          
       } 
           } else {
           next
                }

 for(i in seq_along(result2)) {                              
  write.csv2(get(result2[i]),                              
         paste0("Where I want to put my csv files",
                result2[i],
                ".csv"),
                 row.names = FALSE)
```

It takes too long ... I don't even know if it is correct ...

The structure of my json file:

```
{
 "data":[
    {
        "attachments": {
            "media_keys": [
                "3_1630878910203273218"
            ]
        },
        "author_id": "1076649404",
        "created_at": "2023-03-01T10:33:28.000Z",
        "edit_history_tweet_ids": [
            "1630878914296913926"
        ],
        "id": "1630878914296913926",
        "lang": "it",
        "possibly_sensitive": false,
        "public_metrics": {
            "impression_count": 115,
            "like_count": 1,
            "quote_count": 0,
            "reply_count": 0,
            "retweet_count": 1
        },
        "text": "#Europportunit"
    },
    {
        "attachments": {
            "media_keys": [
                "3_1630609124076531716"
            ]

 "includes": {
    "media": [
        {
            "media_key": "3_1630878910203273218",
            "type": "photo",
            "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FqILumJXoAIOzy4.jpg"
        },

 "meta":{
    "newest_id": "1630878914296913926",
    "oldest_id": "1627974617309519873",
    "result_count": 38
  }
   }
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Please save the `RStudio` tag for cases where RStudio is part of the problem.

Comment: LZL, if you mouse over the [tag:rstudio] tag, it says specifically *"DO NOT use this tag for general R programming problems"*. Unless you can clearly communicate why this works in R outside of RStudio and fails when run within the IDE, this tag is inappropriate for the question. (I recognize that it is also one of the most-often abused tags.) It is a common blurring of R and RStudio: the latter is not a programming language.